# Making table cells equal width

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, css-tables

I have the following code html generated via jsx:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center;">
  <table class="table time-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="actionable am-time-cell" colspan="6" role="presentation" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(255, 184, 28); color: rgb(255, 184, 28); font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100; text-align: center; width: 50%;">
          <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center;"><span style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; padding-right: 6px; padding-top: 4px;">AM</span><span class="material-icons">brightness_5</span></div>
        </td>
        <td class="actionable pm-time-cell" colspan="6" role="presentation" style="background-color: rgb(239, 249, 254); border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(0, 43, 73); color: rgb(0, 43, 73); font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100; text-align: center; width: 50%;">
          <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center;"><span style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; padding-right: 6px; padding-top: 4px;">PM</span><span class="material-icons">brightness_3</span></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(0, 43, 73);">
        <td class="actionable hour-picker-cell" colspan="1.5" role="presentation" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; width: 12.5%; min-width: 12.5%;">12</td>
        <td class="actionable hour-picker-cell" colspan="1.5" role="presentation" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; width: 12.5%; min-width: 12.5%;">1</td>
        <td class="actionable hour-picker-cell" colspan="1.5" role="presentation" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; width: 12.5%; min-width: 12.5%;">2</td>
        <td class="actionable hour-picker-cell" colspan="1.5" role="presentation" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; width: 12.5%; min-width: 12.5%;">3</td>
        <td class="actionable hour-picker-cell" colspan="1.5" role="presentation" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; width: 12.5%; min-width: 12.5%;">4</td>
        <td class="actionable hour-picker-cell" colspan="1.5" role="presentation" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; width: 12.5%; min-width: 12.5%;">5</td>
        <td class="actionable hour-picker-cell" colspan="1.5" role="presentation" style="background-color: rgb(239, 249, 254); text-align: center; width: 12.5%; min-width: 12.5%;">6</td>
        <td class="actionable hour-picker-cell" colspan="1.5" role="presentation" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; width: 12.5%; min-width: 12.5%;">7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="actionable timeCell timeCellFuture" role="presentation" colspan="6" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="timeHolder">6:00</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="actionable timeCell timeCellFuture" role="presentation" colspan="6" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="timeHolder">6:30</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="actionable timeCell timeCellFuture" role="presentation" colspan="6" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="timeHolder">6:10</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="actionable timeCell timeCellFuture" role="presentation" colspan="6" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="timeHolder">6:40</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="actionable timeCell timeCellFuture" role="presentation" colspan="6" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="timeHolder">6:20</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="actionable timeCell timeCellFuture" role="presentation" colspan="6" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="timeHolder">6:50</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

But it ends up like this:
[image]

I am wondering is there a way to make width of hour row (second row) all equal width.

jsFiddle which shows the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/1feq5Lm3/

**Update:**

I removed all extra css/scss and all inline styles from `<td>`s in the second row. The result is the same and still width of each cell is not equal: https://jsfiddle.net/6chfqmrs/1/

Comment: When I run this code in Firefox and IE browsers, it looks fine, but when I went to Chrome I saw the width problem. I was able to add `style="width:50%"` to the `<table>` tag, and it looked fine.

Comment: @RobJarvis that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I forked your second jsfiddle and have put a "possible" solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/srbh_ya16/0msbqdLz/

Comment: Seems to be a *Chrome* problem. Just checked with *Firefox* and it looked fine.